# Self Destructing Applescript App bug, how do I make it work?

Tags: macos, applescript

I have been trying to make a AppleScript app which should be able to play the audio file of Moby dick, and then self destruct, but every time when I run it, the app just says that it can’t get file “” of application “”Finder.

```
set thePath to POSIX path of (path to me as text)
tell application "Finder" to delete file thePath
```

This is the script above

`do shell script "/bin/rm " & quoted form of thePath`

I have also tried to use this instead of the tell application, but it didn’t work either.
Can someone tell me what I did wrong, and tell me the correct way of doing it?

Comment: An AppleScript saved as `.app` format is essentially a directory, i.e. it’s a folder, containing multiples files/folders. Therefore you’ll need to utilize the `-rf` options with the shells `rm` utility. For example: 
`do shell script "rm -rf" & space & quoted form of POSIX path of (path to me)`

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing apples and oranges. The following trashes the applet in which it occurs:

```
tell application "Finder" to delete (path to me)
```